# Tricky lagrange optimization problem

Tags: geometry, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm currently stuck with a Lagrange optimization problem where I just can't find the right Lagrangian function.
The problem statement is as follows:

The function $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^4+z^6-1=0$ defines a closed surface area in $\mathbb{R}^3$. This area is symmetric to the three coordinate planes $xy=0$, $yz=0$, $zx=0$. Now place a also symmetric positioned, axis-parallel, **cuboid** in this area in that way, that its surface area is **maximised**.

Formulate a system of equations which solutions give the corner points $(x,y,z)$ of this cuboid. (No need to actually solve this system of equations!)

I know that function to maximise should just be $g(a,b,c)=2(ab+bc+ac)$ and one equality constraint is the given function $f(x,y,z)=0$.

What I'm not sure about is how I get from this resulting Lagrangian function to the eight coordinates (x,y,z) (cause of eight corners) from my cuboid.

Any guidance in the right direction would be really appriciated. I've done a few problems on Langrange optimization yet but I just dont't know where to go with this one.

EDIT: I also thought about including the three equations $xy=0$, $yz=0$, $zx=0$ as equality constraints. Is there a general way to identify which equation is relevant for a equality constraint.

Comment: Oh, as I finished writing this I thought about this: If the cuboid is centered around $(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$ then the coordinates should just be 

$c_1=(a/2,b/2, -c/2)$

$c_2=(a/2,b/2,c/2)$

$c_3=(a/2,-b/2,-c/2)$

$c_4=(a/2,-b/2,c/2)$

$c_5=(-a/2,b/2, -c/2)$

$c_6=(-a/2,b/2,c/2)$

$c_7=(-a/2,-b/2,-c/2)$

$c_8=(-a/2,-b/2,c/2)$

Pretty messy, but it's an attempt. Would this make sense in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lagrangian can be stated as

$$
L = 8(x y + x z + y z)+\lambda(x^2+y^4+z^6-1)
$$

and after solving the stationary conditions

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \cases{2 \lambda  x+8 (y+z)\\ 4 \lambda  y^3+8 (x+z)\\ 6 \lambda  z^5+8 (x+y)\\ x^2+y^4+z^6-1}
$$

we have the solution

$$
\{ x = 0.739178, y = 0.720635, z = 0.754121\}
$$

with a surface of $13.0684$ units.

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you for the reply and this solution! May I ask how you got to the $8(x y + x z + y z)$ term? Wouldn't this be four times the surface area?

Comment: Regarding the plane $xy$ the face parallel has a surface of $4xy$ but we have two such faces so $8xy$. This should be extended to $xz$ and $yz$.